# How to take Node.js stream and send it to form endpoint (dropbox)

Tags: node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a readable stream (s3) that I would like to pipe to dropbox's put endpoint, however this does not support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` required for streaming data.

I see 2 possible solutions

1. read the stream into a variable of some sort then send up, memory can then be a problem
2. write the stream to disk then read it back and upload, which feels dirty and will be slow

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the [/chunked_upload endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#chunked-upload)? That sounds like what you might be after. Also, if you aren't already using it, I've found the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library to be very useful in this type of situation -- it has great sematics for HTTP piping.

Comment: It looks like its not quite the same, its basically a work around where you do multiple normal puts then close it off with a different 'close put' https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox/pull/33#issuecomment-10933744